# Image inside email signature - Outlook email

Tags: html, email, outlook, base64, html-email

I would like to generate Outlook email drafts (.eml files) with the following code. I am able to generate these drafts, however, I am unable to embed/link a logo (png image/external link) under the signature.

I'm not familiar with HTML/Javascript so I'm struggling a bit with this.

My question is, what is the best way to attach the png image/external link of my company's logo in these drafts, bearing in mind that I will need to send them through Outlook and that it does not support base64 images?

I can use an image saved locally on my PC or use one from the internet.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Unsent: 1
To: recipients
Subject: email's subject
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="alternative_boundary"
[BLANK LINE]
--alternative_boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
[BLANK LINE]
--alternative_boundary
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="related_boundary"
[BLANK LINE]
--related_boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
<!DOCTYPE html>
[BLANK LINE]
<html><body> 

EMAIL TEXT

</body></html>
<img src="cid:0123456789">
[BLANK LINE]
--related_boundary
Content-Type: image/png; name="company_logo.png"
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="company_logo.png"
Content-Location: company_logo.png
Content-ID: <0123456789>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
TO BE CHANGED
[BLANK LINE]
--related_boundary--
[BLANK LINE]
--alternative_boundary--
```

Comment: There are tons of similar questions on this. HTML email how to embed images. (Images from internet is the normal way)